# Support Lib r11

Tags: actionbarsherlock

I want to use the new features from the actual release of the support lib r11 (especially the nested fragments). Is this possible with ABS 4.2.0?

Thanks,
Mirco

Answer (score 0):

The latest support lib r11 seems to be working fine with ABS 4.2. I replaced the support lib that comes with ABS 4.2 with version r11 and I havent seen any problems. I'm able to nest fragments.